# android: how to get user photos in Instagram?

Tags: android, instagram

In my app my requirement is to get the user photos and show in my app.

For that i am authenticate , got access token and enter username password but that shows you don't have permission to open this page. next how can i get user profile and photos.

here my code is:

```
 String url ="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?" +"response_type=token" + 
 "&redirect_uri=" + CALLBACK_URL+"&scope=basic"+"&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID ;

  WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            String fragment = "#access_token=";
            int start = url.indexOf(fragment);
            if (start > -1) {

                // You can use the accessToken for api calls now.
                String accessToken = url.substring(start + fragment.length(), url.length());

                Log.v(TAG, "OAuth complete, token: [" + accessToken + "].");
                Log.i(TAG, "" +accessToken);
Toast.makeText(ActivityWebView.this, "Token: " + accessToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this code i got solution from this:

```
 URL example = new URL("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token="
                            + accessToken);

            URLConnection tc = example.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(line);

                JSONArray object = ob.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) object.get(i);
                    JSONObject nja = (JSONObject) jo.getJSONObject(photos);

                    JSONObject purl3 = (JSONObject) nja
                            .getJSONObject("thumbnail");
                    Log.i(TAG, "" + purl3.getString("url"));
                }

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It works with me. But, what about the accessToken? Can I use one fixed accessToken with my app to let too many user get the images using the same accessToken (Concurrent access with same AccessToken)

Comment: u have to generate access token from your client id and secret and use that access token in your app

Comment: Can I use this AccessToken hardcoded into my app to make all user can use the app with this access token? Will this make any problem with the big number of users?

Comment: @SubbaReddyPolamReddy This PhotoSet is a class that you've created?

Comment: what this two lines refers PhotoSet set = new PhotoSet(); and thesets.add(set);

Comment: Nothing related with PhotoSet i.e for my local thong i created that class. u can avoid those two lines..

Answer (score 2):

GET `/users/[USER_ID]/media/recent/?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]`

You can hit this URL to get the user's feed (last 20 photos). This will give you a JSON array that you will then need to parse and display as desired in your app.

Comment: i didn't get any idea from this please elaborate this url

Comment: here USER_ID means either username or client_id...and please give it in a url manner..

Comment: Can I generate one accessToken to use it with multiple users? @SubbaReddyPolamReddy,