# programmatically get shared photos form Instagram in Android

Tags: android, social-networking

I want to integrate Instagram in my Android application. Successfully I finished login, but I don’t know how to get user shared images through Instagram. I have tried so far to get the user info:

```
URL url = new URL(API_URL + "/users/" + mSession.getId() + "/?access_token=" + mAccessToken);
```

Then I got a link for to get user photos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505956/android-how-to-get-user-photos-in-instagram), but on that link I don’t know what is `PhotoSet set = new PhotoSet(); and  thesets.add(set);`.

Anyone please explain the above link or give me any other sample code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want, but Instagram does have support for RSS, you can even get the RSS feed for a hashtag. Obviously if they have a proper API you should use it, but sometimes the simplest solution is RSS. Here is [a StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747870/instagram-public-rss-feed) which may help.